# I'm using a colorscheme installed with vim-plug, how can I change the color of the line numbers?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I'm using [this](https://github.com/rakr/vim-one) colorscheme, how can I change the color of the line numbers? I think that the colorscheme will overwrite anything I'll put in .vmrc.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options to accomplish that.

Actually changing the highlight rules after setting the colorscheme in your Vimrc is not a completely unreasonable approach, since the colorscheme is usually only reloaded if you set the [background](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27background%27), so if you tend not to switch from "light" to "dark" or vice-versa, you might be fine...

There are better approaches though.

As recommended in [`:help :colorscheme`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Acolorscheme):

> To customize a color scheme use another name, e.g.
>     `~/.vim/colors/mine.vim`, and use
>   `:runtime` to load the original color scheme:
>
> ```
> runtime colors/evening.vim
> hi Statement ctermfg=Blue guifg=Blue
> ```

It fails to mention you should also set [`g:colors_name`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#g%3Acolors_name), which is what is used to reload the theme after you change the background, so make sure you include this line there:

```
let g:colors_name = 'mine'
```

Except instead of "mine" use the name you used for the colorscheme, the name you used for the `colors/*.vim` file you created.

Another option is to use an `:autocmd`, using the [ColorScheme](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#ColorScheme) event to load additional highlights right after a colorscheme is loaded.

A simplistic example would be:

```
augroup colorscheme_override
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme one highlight LineNr ctermfg=Blue guifg=Blue
augroup END
```

This will only override the "one" colorscheme (use a `*` for the match to override any colorscheme.)

One advantage of the `autocmd` approach is that you don't need a new colorscheme name (but then one disadvantage is that it's harder to pick the unmodified colorscheme.) You don't need to touch `g:colors_name` in the `autocmd` approach, since the original theme will have taken care of that for you already.

The approaches above are a bit naive in that they're setting colors regardless of whether the background is light or dark. Typically you would want to check for that to decide on it. Use a block similar to:

```
if &background ==# 'light'
  highlight LineNr ctermfg=DarkBlue guifg=DarkBlue
else
  highlight LineNr ctermfg=LightBlue guifg=LightBlue
 endif
```

If using a ColorScheme `autocmd`, you probably want to call a function from the `autocmd` and then add all your extra logic there for the overrides, including the blocks for light and dark backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detialed answer. Can't I just edit vim file of the colorscheme I'm using?

Comment: Yes, you can edit it, but that might make it hard to keep it updated with upstream. For instance, if you get it from a plug-in manager, you'll get out of sync...