# Vim highlighting random indentations

Tags: syntax-highlighting, indentation, colorscheme, highlight

[image: Indentation glitch?]

As seen from the image, Vim decides to highlight those indentations for no reason. I've tried `:noh` and `:set nolist` (`:set list` seems to make it go away, but I don't want indentation marks) from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2851094/6276743), but they do not work.

What's causing this issue? All my settings are default, here is my `vimrc` file:

```
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set noexpandtab
color slate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because Vim's HTML syntax will use style `htmlHead` to the text within the `<head>` block and it will link it to syntax group `PreProc`. (The `PreProc` group is meant for pre-processor directives, such as `#include` or `#define` in C/C++.)

The `slate` colorscheme uses a white background (`guibg=white`) for the `PreProc` group, so it ends up styling the whitespace inside `<head>` that way. It doesn't affect the tags themselves (`<meta>`, `<title>`, etc.) because they're styled as `htmlTag` and text within those tags because they're using more specific styles (for example, `htmlTitle`) for the title.

One way to fix this is to override HTML syntax highlighting to unlink it from `PreProc`, which you can do with:

```
:hi link htmlHead None
```

If you want to make that permanent, add this command to your vimrc. (This will work because `html.vim` sets it using `hi def link` which won't override your settings from your vimrc.)

Another alternative is to override the background color of theme `slate`, which you can do with:

```
:hi PreProc guibg=NONE
```

You can make that stick by adding this command to your vimrc after `color slate`, but the customization will go away if you change themes and then go back to `slate`. (See [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/21670/18609) about how to override an existing color theme in a somewhat more reliable way.)

Comment: I thoroughly recommend @D.BenKnoble's [synstax plug-in](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax) to debug this type of issue. Very useful to display which syntax style is under the cursor.